# Mostrar datos de B.D. en un select de HTML

Tags: php, html, mysqli

Buenas gente, bueno he aquí mi problema, tengo una página en php con las vista html, vamos una página de toda la vida, a la cuál se accede después de un login, ya he verificado que después del login los datos importantes, es decir el ID y el Nombre del usuario se pasan de forma correcta. 
Ahora, dentro de mi página tengo un select del cuál quiero "llenar" sus opciones con información de una tabla de mi base de datos, es decir, dependiendo del Id del usuario se mostrarán distintas opciones. El usuario ingresa como acopiador y debe tener una selección de los productores que le corresponden solo a él. Ahora el problema es que he hecho distintos intentos de distintas formas pero no logro hacer que se muestre la información.

Ésta es la página en cuestión:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Su código es éste:

```
 <?php
    session_start();
    error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
   if(!isset($_SESSION['usuario']) and $_SESSION['estado'] != 'Autenticado') {
    header('Location: logeo.php');
    } else {
    $nombre = $_SESSION['usuario'];
    $id = $_SESSION['id'];
    $salir = '<a href="salir.php" target="_self">Cerrar sesión</a>';
    require('sesiones.php');
    };
    include('conexion.php');
?>
```

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/Merico.png"/>
  <title>Grupo Merino Registro</title>
  <!-- CSS  -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/materialize.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen,projection"/>
  <link href="css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen,projection"/>
  <link href="css/footer.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
  ga('create', 'UA-102894505-1', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="navbar-fixed">
  <nav class="white" role="navigation" id="merhead">
    <div class="nav-wrapper container navbar-fixed-top">
      <a id="logo-container" href="index.html"> <class="brand-logo"><img src="img/Logino.png" style="width:15%" alt="Image"></a>
      <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
        <li><h4 class="header center brown-text text-darken-2">Registro de producto para Acopiadores</h4></li>
        <li><?php echo $salir; ?></p></li>
      </ul> 
      <ul id="nav-mobile" class="side-nav">
        <li><h4 class="header center brown-text text-darken-2">Registro de produto para Acopiadores</h4></li>
        <li><p><?php echo $salir; ?></p></li>
      </ul>
      <a href="#" data-activates="nav-mobile" class="button-collapse brown-text text-darken-2">Menú</a>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>

<div class="card-panel #009688 teal">
<center><h4>Registro del acopiador:  <?php echo $nombre; ?></h4></center>

   <div class="card-panel #80deea cyan lighten-3">    
      <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s4">
          <div class="selector-productor">
            <select id="productor" name="px">
              <option value="0" disabled selected>Seleccione un Productor</option>

            </select>
            <label for="nombre">Nombre de productor: </label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="input-field col s4">
          <input name="kilos" type="number" class="validate" required autofocus min="1">
          <label for="kilos">Kilos: </label> 
        </div>
        <div class="input-field col s4">
          <input name="precio" type="number" class="validate" required autofocus min="1">
          <label for="precio">Precio: </label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <center><button class="btn waves-effect waves-light cyan darken-3" type="submit" value="submit"  name="registrar">Registrar<i class="material-icons right">send</i></button></center>
      </div> 
</div>

</body>

<footer class="footer.css">
  <div class="footer-copyright">
    <div class="container">
      <center><a class="brown-text text-lighten-3" href="http://www.grupomerino.com.mx/">Copyright © 2014 Grupo Merino</a></center>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
   <!--  Scripts-->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/materialize.js"></script>
  <script src="js/init.js"></script>

  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('select').material_select();
    });
  </script>
</html>
```

Y si, tengo un archivo aparte que se encarga de la conexión de base de datos:

```
    <?php
    // Parametros a configurar para la conexion de la base de datos 
    $host = "localhost";    
    $basededatos = "merino_sis";     
    $usuariodb = "root"; 
    $clavedb = "";    

    //Lista de Tablas
    $tabla_db1 = "acopiadores";         // tabla de los acopiadores.
    $tabla_db2 = "productores";         // tabla de los productores.
    $tabla_db3 = "registros_a";         // tabla de los registros de los acopiadores.
    $tabla_db4 = "registros_p";         // tabal de los registros de los productores.

    $conexion = mysqli_connect($host,$usuariodb,$clavedb,$basededatos);

    if ($conexion->connect_errno) {
        echo "La conexión a la Base de Datos ha resultado en un fallo";
        exit();
    }
?>
```

No sé realmente que hacer, me han dado la opción de introducir el siguiente código dentro de la etiqueta "SELECT" pero lo único que hace es que en mi página no aparezca ningún campo para los datos, ni el botón o siquiera el footer:

```
 <?php
            $query="SELECT id,nombre_p FROM `productores` WHERE id_ac='".$id."'";
              $result = mysqli_query($query)
              or die("Ocurrio un error en la consulta SQL");
                mysqli_close();
              while (($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) != NULL) {
                echo '<option value="'.$fila["id"].'">'.$fila["nombre_p"].'</option>';}
          ?>
```

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bueno, puedo pensar en un par de cosas que estén pasando así que de inicio recomiendo confirmar el nivel de error que reportará PHP con lo siguiente:

```
ini_set('display_errors', true);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Luego, estás usando las funciones `mysqli` para conectarte pero `mysql` (obsoletas) para el query de abajo, esto no envía ningún error actualmente pero debería hacerlo al confirmar el nivel de error.

Finalmente, no es necesario cerrar la base de datos puesto que la siguiente ejecución de este u otros scripts podría usar esta misma conexión eliminando así el overhead de crear una nueva en cada llamado.

También agregamos una última opción creada por PHP fuera del loop para saber que nuestro script se ejecuta completamente.

Al final, pensando que quieres que las opciones sean llenadas en el `SELECT` `productor` y que el query a tu base de datos es correcto, el código quedaría algo similar a esto:

```
        <select id="productor" name="px">
          <option value="0" disabled selected>Seleccione un Productor</option>
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', true);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

  $query="SELECT id,nombre_p FROM `productores` WHERE id_ac='".$id."'";
  $result = mysqli_query($conexion, $query) or die("Ocurrio un error en la consulta SQL");
  while (($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) != NULL) {
     echo '<option value="'.$fila["id"].'">'.$fila["nombre_p"].'</option>';
  }
echo '<option>Esta es la última opción y solo es para verificar que sirve el código PHP.</option>'
?>

        </select>
```

Comment: He intentado con la solución que dices pero me genera el mismo problema que comenté antes, mi página queda así tras agregar esas líneas de código.
https://i.gyazo.com/e171cafcf4647cca3acbc50e5e441989.png 
paso la captura por link porque no supe como poner imagen aquí aunque creo no se puede.

Comment: Agrega `ini_set('display_errors', true);` y `error_reporting(E_ALL);` al inicio de tu script y revisa el HTML que resulte de ello. Al parecer PHP no está enviando error alguno.

Comment: Me dio el mismo resultado sin cambio alguno

Comment: Presiona `f12` para abrir la consola de google chrome, en la pestaña `Network` debes poder ver el archivo que contiene el código HTML. Haciendo click en ese archivo puedes ver los detalles, luego en response puedes ver hasta dónde se ejecutó el script PHP y probablemente el error que no se muestra en el HTMl.

Comment: Vale, según la consola se ejecuta hasta éste punto:
<select id="productor" name="px">
              <option value="0" disabled selected>Seleccione un Productor</option>
                <br />
<b>Warning</b>:  mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\just\intacopiador.php</b> on line <b>72</b><br />
Ocurrio un error en la consulta SQL

Comment: Y en mi línea 72 lo que tengo es ésto:
$result = mysqli_query($query) or die("Ocurrio un error en la consulta SQL");

Comment: Es correcto, se me pasó agregar la variable de la conexión mysqli, acabo de actualizar el código para agregar la variable `$conexion` a la función del query.

Comment: Oh dios mio, ya se solucionó, tienes razón, muchas gracias en verdad, aaahhh no sé como agradecerte, en serio gracias por tu ayuda, tiempo y paciencia.

Comment: Es un placer, que bueno que se ha solucionado. Recuerda que si esta respuesta es correcta no olvides marcarla como tal para cerrar el ciclo de esta pregunta. Saludos!